# .htaccess redirect multiple domains

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, redirect

How can I redirect

```
sample-domain.com
sample-domain.eu
www.sample-domain.com
www.sample-domain.eu
```

to for example

```
www.sample-domain.com.pl
```

via 1 condition + rewriterule? For now I'm using 4 conditions with 4 (for www and non www) rewriterules witch is pretty bad I guess.

Answer (score 1):

The following rule should do:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?sample-domain\.(com|eu)$
RewriteRule ^ http://www.sample-domain.com.pl%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Comment: I'll test it tomorrow at work and let you know :) I think I've tested something similar, but I'll check again. Thank you.